# register_post_type in wordpress no working template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have problem with function "register_post_type" in wordpress.

I add code in functions.php (theme path):

```
add_action( 'init', 'events' );

function events() {
  register_post_type( 'events', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Wydarzenia',
      'singular_name' => 'events',
     ),
    'description' => 'Wydarzenia',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
  ));
}
```

And i add template: single-events.php and archive-events.php but this no working... everytime show: index.php..

single.php no working for events...

**Where is problem? Thanks!**

Comment: 'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => events' )  add slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `page-events.php`

After creating your post type `events`. In your WP admin, create a page called `events` and then in code create a page `page-events.php` and then show the listing of all events that u have created in ur custom post type `events`

```
<?php
$args = array
(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$events_query = new WP_Query($args);?>
<?php if($events_query->have_posts()):?>
    <ul>
        <?php while($events_query->have_posts()): $events_query->the_post();?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

then you can create a `single-events.php` to show content of a single event.

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'init', 'events' );

function events() {

register_post_type( 'events', array(

```
'labels' => array(

  'name' => 'Wydarzenia',

  'singular_name' => 'events',

 ),

'description' => 'Wydarzenia',

'public' => true,

'menu_position' => 20,

'has_archive'   => true,

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => events' ),

'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
```

));
}

see i have added this code there 
'has_archive'   => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => events' ),
it will work fine.

if u are not able to get the page after putting this code , u have to go to permalink and change the url sure it will work.